# Running Multiple instance of Master Node will lead any Performance Issue in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, git

Code sample :

```
var cpuCoreLength = require("os").cpus().length;
var cluster = require("cluster");
if(cluster.isMaster){
cluster.setupMaster({
  exec : "child.js"
  });
   var JOB_QUEUE=["data1","data2","data3"]; //for this post, value inserted manually.
   for(var i=0;i<cpuCoreLength;i++){
    var worker = cluster.fork();
     worker.on("message",function(data){
        if(data.type == "SEND_DATA"){
        worker.send({"data":JOB_QUEUE[0]});
        }
     });
    }

}
else
{
   process.send("type":"SEND_DATA"});
   process.on("message",function(data){
     //Do the Process
   });
}
```

Hi this is sample code for my process.In the above code JOB_QUEUE is data that to be processed by worker. when new worker created one data will be pushed to worker. Worker will use common file specified in the Master Setting. This is one copy of Master. I am going to create like 5 Master Code with different JOB_QUEUE but same child file. bcoz every master node going to handle different set of data and each master to be processing with 1000000 of data. To monitor data processed by worker purpose i created separate Master. My question, will it lead any performance Issue in Terms of CPU or due to CPU core if i run Multiple Master Node?

Comment: you can run it and check the cpu usage. What is stopping you?

Comment: ya i can do and check... but doing like this is right procedure Mukesh Soni?

Comment: no it's not. You can easily handle the different data in the same master. Just pass the different data to different children. You don't need multiple masters.